# Basics to learn Adobe aftereffect

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I am new to adobe after effect. i want to design a film detail in adobe after effect...give some tutorial websites and example ebook.

i just begin to learn adobe after effects. i have more interest in directing a film. i want to  use adobe after effect for my film title and for others. For this i have to learn more about after effect.

i already tried reading [ae tutsplus](http://ae.tutsplus.com). if you know other tutorial websites and books.. kindly refer to me

Comment: Your question isn't related to programming. Could it be migrated to [Audio-Video Production](http://avp.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google it you can find lots of tutorial.
I will simplify your work Just use this tutorials given below.

[videocopilot](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/)

[creativecow](http://library.creativecow.net/tutorials/adobeaftereffects)

[hongkiat](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/adobe-after-effect-tutorials-beginners-intermediate-advanced-users/)

These sites having lots of tutorials learn them